# average of one field for each column in a related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am starting my quest to

So I have two tables in my database that I want to join and do statistics on.

the first table has the format (all the fields are logical values):

global_id , logical1 ,logical2, logical3, ...

The second has the format (created with a nested select):

global_id, float1

I want to look at the group statistics of float1 in each logical value in table 1 without writing 30 queries. My goal is to do it in native sql to allow for future translation to an expert who will build our db. This is currently for a research project.

What I want is a result table that looks like

```
          | AVG(float1) | STDEV(float1) | Max(float1) | Min(float1) 
logical1

logical2

logical3
```

I thought this would be a crosstab type query but it turns out to not be as easy as I thought.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: As logicalN are fields they are finite, how many are they? Because this query is a `PIVOT` and, as far as I know, to do that in MySQL the only way is to use a `CASE`

Comment: Based on what you've shown, for any given global_id the aggregated values will be the same for all "logical" values. Is this true, or  does the first table also contain a "logical" value so each "logical" value can have different aggregated values?

Comment: Serpiton - well the basis for the logical is gene mutations in the human genome, so quite a lot


Bohemian for each global_id the values are different. The aggregate data will be different because it is possible only 100 of 1000 have a TRUE value in each logical.

Comment: @user3648459 You need to edit this question adding information. Rigth now I don't understand how the statistical values are calculated, e.g. what is the logic that translate the two data tables to the result? You say that the second table is a nested select, what is the base table for that select? There are not enough element to start working on an answer, also an example of data and results will be nice for testing. One last thing, without a @ before the nick SO don't recognize it as a nick and don't send the message to other inboxes